# Taking average values in column B if column A has the same date but different time

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a panda dataframe which has a column with the data and time and another column with a float value. now I want to take an average of the values in the second column if the date is the same irrespective of the time and want to display just one value for that date.
can anyone help with that?

E.g-

```
**1st row**- Column A - '2018-12-08 04:51:58', Column B- '3', Column C- '4'
**2nd row**- Column A - '2018-12-08 04:51:49', Column B- '2', Column C- '3'
**3rd row**- Column A - '2018-12-08 04:51:57', Column B- '1', Column C- '2'
```

The output that I want is :

```
Column A- '2018-12-08', Column B- '2', Column C- '3'
```

**P.S** the `dtype` for column A is `datetime64[ns]`, and i have over 3k rows with different datetime and values

Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** As you say your dataframe is `datetime64[ns]`, something like:

```
    date                C
0   2018-09-14 00:00:00 4
1   2018-09-14 00:10:00 3
2   2018-09-14 01:10:00 2`
```

use:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date).mean().reset_index()
```

or :

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('d')).mean().reset_index()
```

**Output**:

```
    date        C
0   2018-09-14  3
```

For getting the sum and dividing by 2:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date).apply(lambda x : x['C'].sum()/2).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'new'})
```

or (one more method which i just found)

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('d')).apply(lambda x : x['C'].sum()/2).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'new'})
```

**Output**:

```
    date        new
0   2018-09-14  4.5
```

Comment: im getting this error AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Comment: is it okay to convert the datatype to string? if so, you can use `df.astype(str)` ? and check if it works?

Comment: So i have 3 columns in total first being the data and the other being the coumns with value i want to find the mean. Cant i work with datetime64? as i need to merge this with another dataframe according to the date.

Comment: are you sure the data has `Sept` and not `Sep`? I am not able to reproduce the issue with `Sept`

Comment: sept was just an example. the actual data is in this format "2018-12-08 04:51:58" . i tried normalizing the data like it makes all the time 00:00:00 and just returns the date but im not able to combine all the dates and return just one value. groupby doesnt work

Comment: you should never post such examples, i was under the assumption that your data looked like `Sept`  and ended up wasting too much time, always advised to post sample of your data. Please keep this in mind, will get back with a solution soon.

Comment: okay. iv edited the question you can go through it once again. thanks!

Comment: nope. still not working. it just gives the output as is. doesnt combine the date or gives means for values

Comment: if your column name is not `date` it wont work, replace the `date` column with the oriinal column name

Comment: @AvijeetSingh : how about :- `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('d')).apply(lambda x : x['C'].sum()/2).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'new'})` replace `'date'` with the original names of date column which you have. May be you have `'Column A'` and not `'date'`

Comment: You ca also add `B` column, but `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date).mean().reset_index()` looks good.

Comment: @jezrael : thanks, however, seems its not working for OP. :( any reason you can think of?

Comment: @anky_91 - So it seems data related problem, the best ask for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okat. :) Thanks @jezrael